# Como instalar o python-yaml?

Tags: python, ubuntu, yaml

eu instalei o módulo python-yaml numa versão anterior a que estou usando agora, usando apt-get install python-yaml, porém agora quando fui tentar usar o módulo na nova versão ele diz que não tem o módulo instalado, e quando vou instalar ele diz que já está instalado. Alguém me diz como proceder?

Comment: Que versões? Do python ou da biblioteca?

Comment: Do python, eu tinha a versão 2.7.12 instalada e baixei a 2.7.14. Eu tinha instalado o módulo na 2.7.12, quando deixei a 2.7.14 padrão esse python não tem o módulo, porém quando tento instalar ele instala no 2.7.12. Mesmo eu desinstalando e instalando ele não instala no novo padrão.

Comment: Você possui essas duas versões do Python instaladas? Como faz para diferenciar qual quer executar? Existe mesmo a necessidade de se manter as duas instaladas?